# Configure product custom options for different store views

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, store-view

i want to use the product Custom option in admin panel
but i have 2 stores view and i want it should show only in Store 1 and Not store 2 
now is it set for global and not for website or store
for example when i create a drop down menu it showing on both stores even if i chooise only 1 store in the Choose Store View:
[image]

Comment: did you find an answer for this yet?

Comment: no, im still looking for an option

Comment: any body can help me?